# Saving data offline

Tags: javascript

I am working on a small management game made with html/css and javascript.
The all thing is offline, there is no server side, I only use html as a GUI.

The player should be able to save his progress, so I am looking for a way to save data on the client side.
The data will be about 200/300 objects with about 10 variables in each.

Is there a way to create a “save file” or some kind of database with javascript?

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The player should be able to save his progress, so I am looking for a way to save data on the client side. The data will be about 200/300 objects with about 10 variables in each.

You can save `JSON` to [WebStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Use either:

- `localStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- `sessionStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Is that ok for large amount of data? I saw it when I looked online but thought it was to save small variables.

Comment: _"Storage limit is [...] 5MB."_ (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)